# Gspread Not Working with Google Colab "Authenticate User" and Oauth2Client

Tags: google-colaboratory, gspread, oauth2client

In Google Colab, when using the example below, I am now getting an error.  This worked for years, it stopped working today for me.

When utilizing the example:

**Cell 1**

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

**Cell 2**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())`
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ac9436b5eeee> in <module>()
      2 from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
      3 
----> 4 gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())


/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/__init__.py in authorize(credentials, client_class)
     38     """
     39 
---> 40     client = client_class(auth=credentials)
     41     return client

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py in __init__(self, auth, session)
     38     def __init__(self, auth, session=None):
     39         if auth is not None:
---> 40             self.auth = convert_credentials(auth)
     41             self.session = session or AuthorizedSession(self.auth)
     42         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/utils.py in convert_credentials(credentials)
     57 
     58     raise TypeError(
---> 59         "Credentials need to be from either oauth2client or from google-auth."
     60     )
     61 

TypeError: Credentials need to be from either oauth2client or from google-auth.
```

I don't know where to go from here. I reached out to Google Cloud support, but realized this was out of their scope.  The authentication flow is working from a Google standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Google colab has recently changed their API. The old API has been deprecated and a new one is made available.

Here is a the new code snipet that is provided by Google and works fine with `gspread`

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

sh = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')
```

Comment: That's it. Looks like oauth is dead and this is the new norm.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the runtime and follow a new protocol. I think what we were using before is now deprecated...

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/sheets.ipynb#scrollTo=6d0xJz3VzLOo

(As per comment, relevant snippet copied for future posterity)

```python
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

Comment: This is a solid answer as it points to a Google reference/sample doc but Lavigne958's answer doesn't require an external reference to visit. In about 5 years, that'll matter since many links die but chunks of code on SO live forever.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the authentication method following [this guide](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access)

1. Head into [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. In the box labeled “Search for APIs and Services”, search for "Google Drive API" and "Google Sheets" and enable it
3. Go to “APIs & Services > Credentials” and choose “Create credentials > Service account key”.
4. Fill out the form
5. Click “Create” and “Done”.
6. Press “Manage service accounts” above Service Accounts.
7. Press on ⋮ near recently created service account and select “Manage keys” and then click on “ADD KEY > Create new key”.
8. Select JSON key type and press “Create”.

You're going to get a json like this:

```json
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "api-project-XXX",
    "private_key_id": "2cd … ba4",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nNrDyLw … jINQh/9\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "473000000000-yoursisdifferent@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "473 … hd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ...
}
```

9. Go to your spreadsheet and share it with a `client_email` from the step above. Just like you do with any other Google account.
10. Put the json file inside a folder in your drive
11. Change your cells to:

```py
import gspread

json_dir = 'drive/MyDrive/credentials/credentials.json'

gc = gspread.service_account(filename=json_dir)
```

where `json_dir` is the path to json file created in step 8

Hope it helps